# How to redirect site to https and http using htaccess for specific file and folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site that I wanna change https to http for only '/wp-admin' and 'wp-login.php'. I wanna use .htaccess to achieve it, but I m not good at regular expressions. Below is my current htaccess codes.

```
# Force HTTPS for /my
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\s/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteRule !^wp-admin https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Force HTTP for anything which isn't /my
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(wp-admin) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Currently it works for wp-admin/, but not for /wp-login.php. How to modify this?

Comment: Why would you want to serve your admin panel and logins over HTTP? Surely **those** are the things you'd want HTTPS to secure the most, right?

Comment: By right yes, but in https, my 100+ cforms are not working. The site was previously in http. But after installing SSL, the cforms went haywire. Temporary solution is to disallow https at admin dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your Rules with this :

```
RewriteEngine on
#http to https except "/wp-admit" and "/wp-login.php"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^((?!wp-admin.*|wp-login\.php).*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#Redirect "/wp-admin" and "/wp-login.php" to http if accessed using https scheme
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(wp-admin.*|wp-login\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing these rules.